# User authentication through REST web service on a different domain - asp.net

Tags: asp.net, json, restful-authentication

I am looking to connect to a web service on a different domain in order to authenticate users.  The Web Service itself is a RESTful service, written in Java.  Data is passed to and from it in JSON.

I initially tried to connect using jQuery (see below)

```
        function Login()
    {
        $.ajax({
        url: "http://www.externaldomain.com/login/authenticate",  
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: "{'emailAddress':'bob@bob.com', 'password':'Password1'}", 
        success: LoadUsersSuccess,
            error: LoadUsersError
        });         
    }
    function LoadUsersSuccess(){
        alert(1);
    }
    function LoadUsersError(){
        alert(2);
    }
```

However, when checking on Firebug, this brought up a 405 Method Not Allowed error.

At this stage, as this is the first time I've really worked with web services, I really just wondered whether this was the best way to do things?  Is it worth persevering with this method in order to find a solution, or am I best to maybe try and find a server-side answer to this issue?  If so, does anyone have any examples they could post up?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I got the problem solved, and I did it by going back to C# and doing it there instead of using jQuery or JSONP and I used Json.Net for handling the data received.  Here is the code:

```
protected void uxLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();
data.Append("{");
data.Append("'emailAddress': '" + uxEmail.Text + "', ");
data.Append("'password': '" + uxPassword.Text + "'");
data.Append("}");

byte[] byteData = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data.ToString());
string url = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AuthenticationURL"].ToString();

string JSONCallback = string.Empty;
Uri address = new Uri(url);

// Create the web request  
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(address) as HttpWebRequest;

// Set type to POST  
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/json";
// Create a byte array of the data we want to send  

// Set the content length in the request headers  
request.ContentLength = byteData.Length;

// Write data  
using (Stream postStream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    postStream.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length);
}

// Get response  
using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
{
    // Get the response stream  
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

    // Console application output  
    JSONCallback = reader.ReadToEnd().ToString();
}


if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(JSONCallback))
{
    JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(JSONCallback);
    if ((bool)jObject["loginResult"] == false)
    {
        string errorMessage = jObject["errorMessage"].ToString();
        int errorCode = (int)jObject["errorCode"];
    }
    else
    {
        string idToken = jObject["idToken"].ToString();
        Session["Userid"] = idToken;
        Response.Redirect("~/MyDetails.aspx");
    }
}
else
{
    uxReturnData.Text = "The web service request was not successful - no data was returned";
}
```

}

Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

Doing cross-domain web service calls in a browser is very tricky.  Because it's a potential security vulnerability, browsers block these types of requests.  However, there is a workaround called JSONP.  If you use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) instead of plain JSON, you should be able to make the cross-domain request.

Answer (score 1):

Right ok, to update where I am, I checked in firebug and on the external server and the reason why I'm getting a 405 error is because I'm doing a Get rather than a Post.

What I need to do is send the username and password, then receive a GUID back which will then be used for any future requests.  I thought by having 'type:post' in the code would be enough but apparently not.  Anyone know where I might be going wrong here?  As I said, a novice to web services and nothing I have tried from looking online has had any effect.  Many thanks